# Molecular dynamics: trajectories of particles in 2D

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to figure out how to plot trajectories of particles as it is computed.

I am having a hard time figuring out where to start.

The picture below is what I want it to look like because later, I would want to plot the speed and velocity distribution of these trajectories with maxwells distribution equation.

[image: molecular dynamic trajectories]

Here is my code so far

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

from numpy.random import rand
from scipy.linalg import norm

def F(pos,vel,n,nsteps):
for tsteps in range(nsteps-1):
    i=0
    vel[i] = vel[i]
    pos[i] = pos[i] + vel[i] * dt
    if pos[i,0] > L:
        pos[i,0] = pos[i,0] - L
    elif pos[i,0] < 0:
        pos[i,0] = pos[i,0] + L
    elif pos[i,1] > L:
        pos[i,1] = pos[i,1] - L
    elif pos[i,1] < 0:
        pos[i,1] = pos[i,1] + L
        vel[i,1] *= -1
    if tsteps%1 == 0:
        plt.scatter(pos[i,0],pos[i,1],color="b",s=2)
        plt.draw()
n=1
L=10
nsteps=200
dt=0.28   
pos=np.zeros([n,2])
vel=np.zeros([n,2])


plt.figure(figsize=[8,8])
plt.axis([0,L,0,L])
plt.ion()

plt.show()

pos_init = np.array([0,0])
vel_init = np.array([-1,-0.31456])

pos[0,:] = pos_init[:]
vel[0,:] = vel_init[:]

t0= time.time()
F(pos,vel,n,nsteps)
print("execution time = " , time.time()- t0)
```

Comment: Two separate issues: How to generate the data you want and how to plot it in 2D.  The second one is easy; the first one is hard.

Comment: well v =1 and the box would be a 20 x 20 with 81 particles in it or so. dt would be 0.02. I just dont know where to start

Comment: I'd start with one particle in a box. Work out the differential equation and how you'll deal with collisions. When one works you can add more. How do particles interact?  Piloting is separate from behavior. Get that right with text output first.

Comment: ok for sure. Let me try it and ill add updated code

Comment: You're problem isn't code; it's the physics.  Get that right and the code will follow.